# Examine the continuity and discontinuity of the following function at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Examine the continuity and discontinuity of the following function at $(0,0)$

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}{x^3\cos({1\over y})+y^3\sin({1\over x})\over {x^2+y^2}} & x\neq 0\neq y\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I tried to prove continuity using the definition of limits

$$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=|{x^3\cos({1\over y})\over x^2+y^2}|+|{y^3\cos({1\over x})\over x^2+y^2}|$$

$$\le|{x^3+y^3\over x^2+y^2}|$$

what do i do next ? Need some hint on proving differentiability as well .

Comment: How do we define $f$ where $x=0\neq y$ (or vice versa)?

Comment: nothing is given in that regard @JonathanY. does the question look incomplete ?

Comment: Naturally, since there are points matching this description in any neighborhood of zero, the way the function is defined there is essential to the solution of the exercise. As the answers imply, the only way to get a limit at the origin is to have the function tend to zero along the axes as well (and whatever we might do won't help with differentiability).

Comment: @JonathanY. I have edited the question. Does it make some sense now ? I think i can show that the partial derivatives doesn't exist now ?

Comment: by finding $f_x$ and $f_y$ and showing that they are not defined at $(0,0)$ and hence the function cannot be differentiable at that point.

Comment: Your change was superficial: it didn't change the definition of the function. I proposed a different change that I suspect was in the original question; please review it. If I'm right, then $f_x$, $f_y$ do exist and are zero at the origin, but $\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ has no limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.

Comment: Oh, I see now @njguliyev suggested (and addressed) that change 10 hours ago.

Comment: ok, i can prove that the partial derivatives exist. but i did not understand what is $|(f(x,y)\over {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|$

Comment: It's the definition of differentiability: $\frac{|f(x,y) - f(0,0) - \langle\nabla f(0,0),(x,y)\rangle|}{\|(x,y)\|}$

Comment: got it !!! Thanks a lot !! i just needed to have courage to work on this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\left|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right| = |x|\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le |x|.$$

Comment: how did you establish the last inequality ?

Comment: $x^2+y^2 \ge x^2$.

Comment: oh ! Nice, and some hint of differentiability please !

Comment: By the way, you didn't define your function at points of the form $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$, but I assume by continuity that $f=0$ at those points. Then $f_x(0,0) = f_y(0,0)=0$. Hence differentiability is equivalent to $f(x,y)=o(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$. That is you have to check whether $\frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\to 0$ or not.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Try polar coordinates: $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. Your bound at the RHS decomposes into a radial component (limiting to zero as $r\downarrow0$) and a bounded angular component.

Differentiability: Jonathan Y. correctly pointed out that neither of the axes (except for the origin) belongs to your domain of definition, so you can't use nonexistence of partial derivatives. We still need to show that one cannot find a & b such that $f(x,y)-f(0,0) = a x + b y + \varepsilon_x x + \varepsilon_y y$, with $\varepsilon_x\to0$ and $\varepsilon_y\to0$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. There's nothing special about partial derivatives: if the function is differentiable, then all *admissible* directional derivatives exist (i.e., in all directions that locally lie within the domain of definition). Use, then, $f(x,x)= x \frac{\cos(1/x)+\sin(1/x)}{2}$. If the function was differentiable, that limit as $x\to0$ would equal $a+b$ - here, it does not exist, which is a contradiction.

Comment: should i use polars on the last inequality i get  ?

Comment: @AmanMittal - yes! Re: differentiability, what have you tried out?

Comment: i get something like this $|r||\cos^3 \theta+\sin^3 \theta|$ But i still dont see how that leads to a limit

Comment: well, for diff i tried using the definition - $f(0+h,0+k)-f(0,0)=hA+kB+h\phi (h,k)+k \theta (h,k)$ but didnt reach anywhere :)

Comment: The angular component is trivially bounded by $2$. As for $r$, it approaches zero because $(x,y)=(0,0)$ corresponds to $r=0$.

Comment: got it, an i trying the right way for diff ?

Comment: i think the function will not be differentiable at $(0,0)$ as its partial derivatives do not exists at $(0,0)$ . am i right ?

Comment: As Jonathan Y. pointed out, the function is not even defined along the axes (except for at the origin), so calculating partial derivatives is out of the question.