# Checking continuity of the function at (0,0). Is the proof correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$
f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\frac{x^{3} \cos \frac{1}{y}+y^{3} \cos \frac{1}{x}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \text { for } x, y \neq 0 \\
0, \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$

I need to check the continuity and differentiability of the function at (0,0).
The idea is to check if limit exists and see if it is equal to the function value at (0,0).

Let $x=r \cos \theta \quad y=r \sin \theta$
$$
\left| \frac{x^{3} \cos \frac{1}{y}+y^{3} \cos \frac{1}{x}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-0 \right|
$$

$$
\begin{array}{l}
=\left| r \cos ^{3} \theta \cos \frac{1}{r \sin \theta}+r \sin ^{3} \theta \cos \frac{1}{r \cos \theta} \right| \\
\leq \left| r \cos ^{3} \theta \cos \frac{1}{r \sin\theta}\right|+\left| r \sin ^{3} \theta \cos \frac{1}{r \cos \theta} \right| \\
=|r|\left|\cos ^{3} \theta \cos \frac{1}{r \sin \theta}\right|+|r|\left|\sin ^{3} \theta \cos \frac{1}{r \cos \theta}\right| \\
\leq | r|+| r| \because\left|\cos ^{3} \theta \cos \frac{1}{r \sin \theta}\right| \leqslant 1\\
=2|r| \\
=2 \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<\epsilon \\
\Rightarrow x^{2}+y^{2}<\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{4}
\end{array}
$$

Let $x^{2}<\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{8}$ and $y^{2}<\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{8}$
$$
\Rightarrow|x|<\frac{\epsilon}{2 \sqrt{2}} \text { and }|y|<\frac{\epsilon}{2 \sqrt{2}}
$$
$$
\text { Let } \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2 \sqrt{2}}
$$
for $\forall \in>0$ $\exists$ $\delta>0$ such thet $|f(x, y)-f(0,0)|<\epsilon$ when $|x|<\frac{\epsilon}{2 \sqrt{2}}$ and $|y|<\frac{\epsilon}{2 \sqrt{2}}$ Hence, limit exists and equal to the function value tf. continuous at $(0,0)$

Is the proof correct? Because when I check this on wolfram I get limit does not exist.
And if it is not how can go about proving or disproving the continuity?  In the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512580/examine-the-continuity-and-discontinuity-of-the-following-function-at-0-0) the answers point out it is continuous. Can wolfram answer be trusted? Although it does say for path in complex plane.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, just use the fact that $|\cos|\le 1$

$\begin{align}|x^3\cos(y^{-1})+y^3\cos(x^{-1})|&\le |x^3\cos(y^{-1})|+|y^3\cos(x^{-1})|\\&\le |x|^3+|y|^3\\&\le \max(|x|,|y|)(x^2+y^2)\end{align}$

Therefore $|f(x,y)|\le\max(|x|,|y|)\to 0$

And the limit is effectively $0$ in the real domain.

*Note: WA is notorious for wrongly evaluating multivariate limits see this simple query to get convinced.*

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=wolfram+wrong+limit+%280%2C0%29